# Create a delay between mouse clicks using Autokey

Tags: python, autohotkey, autokey

I am about to switch from Windows to Ubuntu. Since my mouse keeps doing multiple clicks each time I press the middle mouse button, I used `AutoHotkey` under Windows to add a delay after each click. This worked fine. Now under Ubuntu I want to use `AutoKey` to do the same. `Autokey` uses Python for its scripts though.

Here is the `AutoHotkey` script:

```
MButton::
   If (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 200)
      Return
   Send {MButton}
Return
```

Comment: Do you have an example of an AutoKey script?

Comment: You should consider replacing your mouse, since it can damage the hardware, prevent the system from booting, or trigger unwanted actions.

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger There are quite some example scripts for Autokey in its Wiki: https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki
Nothing similar to what I want to to though.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, (as of version 0.95.4), this is not possible from within AutoKey, because it can’t handle mouse buttons as hotkeys.
This stackoverflow question may be of help: [Triggering AutoKey Script via Mouse Button - How To?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608462)