# Simulate mouse scrolling in Ubuntu

Tags: python, mousewheel, autokey

I using Python [autopilot.input.Mouse](https://phone.docs.ubuntu.com/en/apps/api-autopilot-current/autopilot.input.Mouse) in [AutoKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autokey) for simulate mouse (`move`, `click`) in Ubuntu

and search a solution for

**mouse wheel scrolling down**

My AutKey-Prototype using pyautogui (installed by `pip3 install pyautogui` [linuxhint.com](https://linuxhint.com/gui_automation_pyautogui/)) does nothing:

```
# pip3 install pyautogui
import pyautogui
pyautogui.scroll(20)
```

Any idea how to do that in [Phyton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or [AutoKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autokey)?

#### System

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-52-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Open `AutoKey` and click: `Edit>Preferences>Script Engine>` and select a folder where the pyautogui is located (or contained).

For me that was:

```
home/<my linux username>/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

### Approach

I initially tried:

```
import mouse
mouse.wheel(delta=1)
```

But that requires sudo, and from what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608462/triggering-autokey-script-via-mouse-button-how-to) it appears the AutoKey does not like the `mouse` module too much. Running this script from AutoKey gave the error:

> ImportError:You must be root to use this library on Linux`

Then I tried your module named `pyautogui`. That gave the error that it could not find the module `pyautogui` even though it was installed.

I first installed `pyautogui` on the Anaconda base environment with `pip install pyautogui`. Though it could not find it, so I deactivated anaconda with `conda deactivate` and installed again on the linux python version with `pip install pyautogui`. AutoKey could (still) not find it after restarting AutoKey. But after linking to the package of `pyautogui` it could find it.

### Room for Improvement

I think this solution can be improved by automating it, as it is a basic functionality that one might like in every (new instance) of a Ubuntu OS. Therefore, the AutoKey could be installed automatically, along with the `pyautogui`. If the location is determined where autokey stores this preference, it can be set automatically.

Also, I don't have it working yet in jupyter notebook.